# Expressions for live alone

Tags: idioms, expressions

I believe there are some other ways to say "I live alone". Can you provide me with some expression explaining its formality?

What about these:

- be on (oneself). (?)
- live with (oneself) (?)

Do these kinds of expressions indicate that the person is single or he/she is the only person who lives in the place (maybe he/she meet his/her partner somewhere else?)

Answer (score 1):

The only synonym  I can think of is 'I lived by myself'. I wouldn't use 'oneself' here, as it is *too* impersonal and could be misinterpreted. Neither of these possible sentences suggests you live with a partner. You could, however, say 'I live alone with my partner', or, simply, 'I live with my partner' if it is clear you don't have children.

Answer (score 0):

Just say "I live on my own" and if you have a partner somewhere else that is up to you to tell them.